# What's wrong with my AABB collision detection/resolution code?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, collision

I am working on a game engine in JavaScript, and i'm currently working on the collision system. I made an algorithm to resolve collisions detected with the player, but i'm not getting the intended behavior. Here is the code:

```
if (gameObjects [i].hasComponent ("BoxCollider") == true) {
        for (var x = 0; x < gameObjects.length; x++) {
            if (gameObjects [x].hasComponent ("BoxCollider") == true && gameObjects [i] != gameObjects [x]) {
                if (gameObjects [i].transform.xPos - (gameObjects [i].getComponent ("BoxCollider").width / 2) < gameObjects [x].transform.xPos + (gameObjects [x].getComponent ("BoxCollider").width / 2) && gameObjects [i].transform.xPos + (gameObjects [i].getComponent ("BoxCollider").width / 2) > gameObjects [x].transform.xPos - (gameObjects [x].getComponent ("BoxCollider").width / 2) && gameObjects [i].transform.yPos - (gameObjects [i].getComponent ("BoxCollider").height / 2) < gameObjects [x].transform.yPos + (gameObjects [x].getComponent ("BoxCollider").height / 2) && gameObjects [i].transform.yPos + (gameObjects [i].getComponent ("BoxCollider").height / 2) > gameObjects [x].transform.yPos - (gameObjects [x].getComponent ("BoxCollider").height / 2)) {
                    //collision
                    if (gameObjects [i] == player) {

                        var xPenetration = 0;
                        var yPenetration = 0;

                        //i is left of x
                        if (gameObjects [i].transform.xPos < gameObjects [x].transform.xPos) {
                            xPenetration = -1 * ((/*i right edge*/gameObjects [i].transform.xPos + gameObjects [i].boxCollider.width / 2) - (/*x left edge*/gameObjects [x].transform.xPos - gameObjects [x].boxCollider.width / 2));
                        }

                        //i is right of x
                        else if (gameObjects [i].transform.xPos > gameObjects [x].transform.xPos) {
                            xPenetration = ((/*x right edge*/gameObjects [x].transform.xPos + gameObjects [x].boxCollider.width / 2) - (/*i left edge*/gameObjects [i].transform.xPos - gameObjects [i].boxCollider.width / 2));
                        }

                        //i is top of x
                        if (gameObjects [i].transform.yPos < gameObjects [x].transform.yPos) {
                            yPenetration = -1 * ((/*i bottom edge*/gameObjects [i].transform.yPos + gameObjects [i].boxCollider.height / 2) - (/*x top edge*/gameObjects [x].transform.yPos - gameObjects [x].boxCollider.height / 2));
                        }

                        //i is bottom of x
                        else if (gameObjects [i].transform.yPos > gameObjects [x].transform.yPos) {
                            yPenetration = ((/*x bottom edge*/gameObjects [x].transform.yPos + gameObjects [x].boxCollider.height / 2) - (/*i top edge*/gameObjects [i].transform.yPos - gameObjects [i].boxCollider.height / 2));
                        }

                        if (Math.abs (xPenetration) > Math.abs (yPenetration)) {
                            gameObjects [i].transform.xPos += xPenetration;
                        } else {
                            gameObjects [i].transform.yPos += yPenetration;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, but "but i\'m not getting the intended behavior." don't help us to understand what is the problem, instead a runnable example could help us

Comment: `What's wrong with my […] code?` Your code has no comments indicating purpose/specified behaviour. Your code is hard to read, especially in an SE's code peep-hole. The test `gameObjects [i] == player` looks invariant: move it out of the loop. Reduce the indentation level - short of refactoring, use `continue`-statements. "Eliminate" common sub-expressions like `(gameObjects [i].getComponent ("BoxCollider").width / 2)` at the source-code level. Not stating required and observed behaviour when asking for debugging support is a reason to close a question.

Comment: What's happening? Is it not detecting a collision at all? Is it detecting false positive collisions? Is it detecting it but responding to it incorrectly?

Comment: @samgak thanks for actually being helpful; it does detect the collision but the player glitches out, you can see for yourself in the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of problems. Firstly, you need to handle the case where `gameObjects [i].transform.xPos` is exactly equal to `gameObjects [x].transform.xPos` (and same for the y position). At the moment you are handling less than and greater than but not equal. So just change the `<` to `<=` or the `>` to `>=` e.g:

```
if (gameObjects [i].transform.xPos <= gameObjects [x].transform.xPos)
```

The other problem is that when you collide, it looks more natural if you push an object out of the object it has collided with along the axis with the minimum penetration distance. So just change this line to select the min of x and y instead of the max:

```
if (Math.abs (xPenetration) < Math.abs (yPenetration))
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Everything works pretty good now after that simple change in the second part of your answer